# Identifying Noise in 12AU7 Based Headphone Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, noise, tube

I've been working on making a tube based headphone amplifier as a fun personal project.  The amplifier is based around this [12AU7](https://www.jj-electronic.com/en/ecc82-12au7) vacuum tube.  The project for the most part is following [this existing design](http://diyaudioprojects.com/Solid/12AU7-IRF510-LM317-Headamp/).  It's currently being powered by a 12V lead acid battery.  Here's the circuit diagram:

[image: ckt diagram]

After assembling everything on a piece of perfboard and testing, it sounds great! 
 However, there seems to be an intermittent noise that I can't seem to identify.  This noise is not always present; sometimes the amp will run fine for several minutes without problem, other times the noise will start and last only a few seconds, but sometimes it lasts for minutes at a time.  It appears independent of input. I have heard it while listening to music as well as when no input is connected.  Here's what it looks like.  This was created by recording the output of the amplifier using the line-in of my pc and analyzing the data in Matlab.

[image: noise]

There are strong peaks at 60Hz (I'm in the US) in both channels which makes sense as the input comes from a 1m cable running across my desk.  What I don't understand is the popping.  It also appears to be worse in the left channel despite the two paths being identical.  This is only one sample, but the popping seems to be consistent across occurrences based on what I've heard and other samples I've recorded.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Removing the input.  Even with no input cable connected to the amplifier, this popping is still present.  This also means the noise is independent of the volume set by P1A.
2. Changing the tube.  The noise is present with the extra 12AU7 tube I have and even with no tube.
3. Using different headphones.  I typically use this amp with my Audiotechnica ATH-M40X with a 35 Ohm impedance but the noise exists with my cheap ear buds as well (8 Ohm I think).

This leads me to think that it likely has something to do with either the [IRF510 MOSFET](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91015/sihf510.pdf) or [LM317 linear regulator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317a.pdf) (which is acting as a current source).  I don't know enough about the noise performance of these components to conclusively put the blame on either of them.  If it matters, they both run very hot.  I can record some exact temps later if necessary.  I can't rule out the power source or passives as potential culprits, but again, this is beyond my knowledge.

Any suggestions?  What is the likely cause of this noise?  Are there things I can do to learn more about the noise and narrow down possibilities?  How can I get rid of it?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a bad connection somewhere. That can cause plenty of popping. Double check your solder joints?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Are you running the tube filaments on AC or DC current? Also R1 and R2 could easily be 1M resistors. It this in a metal enclosure?

Comment: Having MOSFET's and LM317's running hot is NOT good at all. Popping noise can be a sign of a bad semiconductor. The popping will get worse with time. What voltage is Vcc and is it the same for the tube anodes?

Comment: @Sparky256 Running off of DC current from a lead-acid battery currently.  It is not in a metal enclosure, right now it's not in any closure at all.  Vcc is nominally 12V and is the only positive voltage rail in the system.

Comment: In the amateur radio literature, the LM78xx regulators are notorious for "popcorn noise".  I'm repeating hearsay here, and that's not the regulator you're using -- but I'd suspect the regulators.  Can you swap one of them out (maybe the left channel, since it's the noisier).

Comment: IMHO, using a 317 as a current source is kind of a stupid pet trick here.  You don't need much precision, and a plain old NPN, properly biased, would work just fine at the cost of needing a couple more resistors.

Comment: Are you sure that pin 9 should be grounded? His PCB layout shows it open. You are applying 12V to each filament. 12V should be applied **between** pin 4 and 5.

Comment: @TimWescott What do you think would be the best way to go about this? Should I try to find a replacement component, configure my DC power supply as a constant current source in it's place, or something else?

Comment: @glen_geek You're totally right.  I somehow completely missed that in the original design.  Although I'm not sure I understand what difference this makes aside from power consumption.  Will it shorten the life of the tube to continue to run it like this?

Comment: You are running filaments very hot - tube life will be shortened considerably.

Comment: @glen_geek: Yeah that's really strange. I imagine running them in series from +12V would still be close enough to the "nominal" 12.6V you would need here (6.3V per heater), right?

Comment: @glen_geek Good to know!  I'll get that patched up so Vcc is split across filaments.

Comment: Voltage divider from +12V to ground that gives you about 2V (this is probably about as good as the LM317 drop-out + adj voltage) and 12mA of standing current or more.  So, 820\$\Omega\$ at the ground end, 4.7k\$\Omega\$ to +12V (note that I'm doing this in my head, check my math).  Transistor that has an HFE of at least 100 at 125mA, and can dissipate 1.5W easily (BD437G, sez DigiKey, along with a couple of hundred others).  Emitter to ground resistor of 10\$\Omega\$.  I give no guarantee it'll work -- but it's what I'd try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at several different forms of transistor and general circuit noise, I accidentally discovered the answer was RF interference from my cell phone.  I'm not sure which specific part signal it is, but I notice it more when my phone is sending and receiving text messages.  My carrier is Verizon and phone Samsung, I don't have access to any others to determine if it is specific to this or a problem in general.

This noise is not unique to my amp.  I've since heard the noise in several solid-state amplifiers including a turntable with built-in equalizer amp and a digital piano with built-in speakers.  I'm assuming the RF interference could be mitigated with some better design, but that will have to wait for another day.